# website in chrome with self-signed certificate is not secure

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, iis

I got a very simple website without any link or something else. I created a self-signed certificate. ([link to create self-signed certificate](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/)). After this I added it to my site in the IIS ([link to add the self-signed certificate to IIS site](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/10/27/configure-iis-to-use-your-self-signed-certificates-with-your-application/)). My Problem is now that my site is still not secure (local). Chrome, Firefox and IE are not accept my certificate. When I look if my certificate is valid: It's valid.

Can Anyone tell me why it's still not secure and how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Self signed certificates are not trusted by default. You need to get the certificate from a trusted CA so that the users web browser trusts it. One recent example of a CA that issues free trusted certificates is [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: When I only want it locally do I need a certificate from a trusted CA too?

Comment: well..  it should be sufficient to add the self signed cert to the trusted certs for your browser/etc

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using WordPress for your blog. Let's try a plugin [really simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/). If you have any certificate install on your site it will detect and convert your pages in https. LetsEncrypt.org also is a way to obtain CA certificate.

You must need to install SSL certificate October 2017 onwards as per Google.

If you need further help read my blog to know that [why we need SSL October onwards.](https://pawanpurohit.com/google-http-pages-warning-make-web-secure/)

Hopefully, your issue will be resolved by a plugin.

Thank you